# Radius of solenoid on the magnitude of magnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, inductance

I'm working on a project and have made a solenoid. I want to know the effective parameters on the magnitude of the magnetic field. $$B=μNi$$
In this equation, the radius of the solenoid don't have any roll. (Because it's for ideal solenoids which the radius compared to the length is too small)

What is the effect of the radius of the solenoid on the magnetic field?

Comment: Do you want to know the field of a non-ideal solenoid?

Comment: no. I do not know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The radius has no impact on the field the wires produce. That is what you are calculating.

If you are looking at the total magnetic field at a point in space, or within the coil, you have to use different equations. 
For magnetic fields within a volume of space, look up Gauss's magnetic field equations (bit of integration in that one) If you are looking for a field at a specific point -> HyperPhysics has a nice tutorial on that here:http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/magnetic/curloo.html#c1.